# Past tenses with hours

Tags: past-tense

1 What did you do at 5 am yesterday?

2 What were you doing at 5 am yesterday?

Guys, in my opinion 1 is correct but 2 needs something more it is incomplete like "What were you doing a 5 am yesterday when the accident happened). My teacher claims that 2 is right because we show the exact time. I state that we need additional activity spoken or implied to make 2 right. Who is correct?

Comment: 5AM (morning) or 5PM (afternoon)? People are generally sleeping at 5am

Comment: (2) is not incomplete. If a crime was committed at 5 a.m., the police might ask a potential witness what they were doing at that exact time.

Answer (score 1):

2 is more normal, since you are probably more interested in activities that were ongoing at 5pm yesterday. It is a normal question to ask.

1 asks for an action that started and finished at 5pm, and only took a moment.  It is an unlikely question.  It is unlikely that it has an answer, or that the person knows the answer.  But it would be possible to ask "What did you do at midnight on Jan 1st" (asking for the momentary action at New Year)

> What did you do at midnight on Jan 1st?
>
> I kissed my boyfriend.

> What were you doing at midnight on Jan 1st?
>
> I was having fun at a party with my friends.

Comment: But we wouldn't for example say "what were you doing yesterday" unless we mean some specific moment like "what were you doing yesterday while I was having fun with my family"  Am I correct? If so could you provide some time border when it is ok to use continuous without additional activity stated or implied and when it isn't?

Comment: Not really,  the situation is as described in the answer.  "At 5pm" is a single point in time.  You use progressive aspects to ask about ongoing actions. You don't need additional activity if you are asking about an ongoing activity.

Comment: So for example: "What were you doing last year" and " What did you do last year" are both fine and I could answer " I was working learning and driving" and " I workrd learned and drove"? No need for any additional activity implied with the past continuous?

Comment: Both fine, with the usual difference in meaning of the progressive aspect.  (though slightly odd to ask about an activity that is ongoing over a whole year...)

Comment: Can you think of any reason why my teachers tell me otherwise. Can it be that English has some for example strict rules when to use the past continuous but natives don't like care about them? I'm lucky enough to  work with PdHs so it's rather unlikely that they claim things like that because they have no knowledge about English

Comment: There are very few strict rules about tenses.  They are a way of communicating meaning.  If the meaning is contradictory it is grammatically correct but it would be something you would never say.  You would never say "What did you do at 5pm yesterday?", as my answer explains.  But this isn't a grammar rule.  It is because the meaning is too strange.  English grammar is mostly about getting the order of the words right, not about tense.

Comment: I asked you about these two " What were you doing last year?" And " What did you do last year?". Just to be sure continuous implies that I this action took place all the time last year whereas simplr simple states that something happened last year but we don't really know how long it lasted. Is that right?

Comment: Too many supplementary questions.  My answer to your question is above

Comment: Can I dicuss with you on the chat?

Comment: "I worked, learned and drove" is not an idiomatic answer.  Depending on context "What did you do last year?" could be a question about last year's holiday/vacation or how you spent Christmas, for example.